# Brave repository for Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, repository, pacman, browser

Is there any Brave browser repository for Arch Linux? I know of binary packages in AUR but I would like to add the repository to pacman configuration so it can be installed and updated on the way as any other package like chromium for example.

Comment: why down-vote with no explanation? that's dumb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution but it requires enabling `snapd` those who use Arch can do this solution.

```
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/snapd.git
cd snapd
makepkg -si
```

Enable it

```
sudo systemctl enable --now snapd.socket

sudo ln -s /var/lib/snapd/snap /snap
```

Now you can install community driven Brave package

```
sudo snap install brave
```

To update run

```
sudo snap refresh brave
```

Works perfect.

Maybe there are another solutions yet or will be.